# LTO compilation question when linking X86/marshal file

Tags: gem5, lto

Envs: Ubuntu 18.04, Miniconda3, python=3.7(GCC=7.3.0), GCC -v (7.4.0)

The error occurs when I run the following command:

```
scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j8
```

The error is as follow:

```
[    LINK]  -> X86/marshal
lto1: internal compiler error: in lto_tag_to_tree_code, at lto-streamer.h:1005
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: g++ returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
/usr/bin/ld: error: lto-wrapper failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [build/X86/marshal] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

And I am wondering how to fix it.

Comment: Possibly related conda build problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65602198/could-not-build-gem5-on-a-machine-with-anaconda Without Conda build does work BTW for me, I would just disable it for gem5.