# Could not build gem5 on a machine with anaconda: "lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream"

Tags: gcc, anaconda, gem5

When I tried to build gem5 with command `scons build/X86/gem5.opt -j12`, I received an error message saying

*lto1: fatal error: bytecode stream in file '/home/beihai/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.8.a' generated with LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 8.1*

I think it might be the problem of wrong gcc version. But I do not know how to fix it.

My system is **Kubuntu 20.04**

By running `gcc -v`, I got the global gcc version **gcc version 9.3.0**

By running `/home/beihai/anaconda/envs/gem5build/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -v`, I got the anaconda gcc version **gcc version 7.3.0 (crosstoll-NG 1.23.0.449-a04d0)**

Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across almost the same issue, except that mine said "LTO version 6.0 instead of the expected 6.2".

I searched for general solution for LTO compatibility issue and got some inspiration from this link: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57176
Quick take from the above link: "I've looked into how this is related to python and found that the error only happens with python installed through anaconda."

So I removed my entire anaconda software package, and removed the build directory inside Gem5, and rerun the scon commands with an additional "--force-lto" arguments, now the installation is successful. Hope it can solve your issue as well.

The command I used: "scons --force-lto build/X86/gem5.opt -j6"

My setups is:
Ubuntu 18 withe kernel 4.15.0-134-generic
g++ --version = g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Recently, I found a more convenient solution. I separate the setup script of anaconda from bashrc. In this way, you do not need to uninstall anaconda anymore. (When I need to use anaconda, I would open a new terminal and source anaconda setup script) Hope this help!